# how to make a chart using data in node.js and express?

Tags: node.js, charts, ejs

I am using chart.js library in node require("chart.js");  and below code in ejs file

```
  function abc () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {

      title:{
      text: "Earthquakes - per month"
      },
       data: [
      {
        type: "line",

        dataPoints: [
        { x: new Date(2012, 00, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 01, 1), y: 414 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 02, 1), y: 520 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 03, 1), y: 460 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 04, 1), y: 450 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 05, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 06, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 07, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 08, 1), y: 410 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 09, 1), y: 500 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 10, 1), y: 480 },
        { x: new Date(2012, 11, 1), y: 510 }
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
<%= abc(); %>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
```

While running it on terminal its shows error.

/var/www/html/nodeproject/helloworld/node_modules/chart.js/Chart.js:668
            return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                   ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at /var/www/html/nodeproject/helloworld/node_modules/chart.js/Chart.js:668:11

how can  draw the chart in ejs format file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve the result to a client, the terminal will not be able to interpret the generated HTML.

You could set up a HttpServer in Node.js and deliver the generated HTML as the response; then in your browser you will be able to see the result.

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
   response.writeHead(200, {'content-type':'text/html'});
   response.end( "<insert genereated html here>" );
});
server.listen(3000); //Or any port you want
```

Comment: i need to generate the chart while my url is look like http://example.com/taglist now in the above solution how can i define app.get and in the insert generated html what would be inserted all the html is generated run time. I have only this html <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>

Comment: I assume you know how to set up a basic Express App ?

then just add a route
`app.get("/<route>", myRoute.render)`

an in your routes folder you put a myRoute.js file in wich you export the render function like `exports.render = function(req, res, next){/*your code herer*/ }`

And I think it would be possible to just send the div back, the browser might just append it to an empty document and display it just fine.

Comment: yes ikarus i know that what about the http which you wrote in above? I need to draw the chart in ejs file. You know how can i draw the chart in ejs view engine my main problem is related that

Comment: Well in your Set `app.Set('view engine', 'ejs');` in your ejs file you set your page Layout and and do `reaponse.render("<your ejs file>");` but if your Chart ist not generated I sadly can not help you, for I have no experience with the CanvasJS

Comment: app.helpers({
  renderScriptsTags: function (all) {
    if (all != undefined) {
      return all.map(function(script) {
        return '<script src="/javascript/' + script + '"></script>';
      }).join('\n ');
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  }
});

app.dynamicHelpers({
  scripts: function(req, res) {
    return ['canvasjs.min.js'];
  }
}); can you please help me why am i getting error related has no method helper

Comment: As far as I know you could just add a script Tag to your ejs like in common HTML , which would make the use of this helper and dynamic helper unnessecary. Maybe it is because of the order in wich you put the code, i mean the script is executed before the div is defined and that could cause an error. But you have to send it as an reaponse and execute the rendered page in a Browser, because node.js does not know of a window object which is mentioned in the error message you posted